# Move uploaded file another directory

Tags: symfony

I am soft deleting a file. Now I want to move soft deleting file 'trashedFile' directory. My soft deleting run, but I can't move to destination folder .
My UploadedFile Entity is below. My file storing in ../uploads/file. If I delete a file move to ../uploads/file/trashedFiles.

My codes:

```
 $deleteFile = $this->em->
 getRepository('AppBundle:UploadedFile\UploadedFile')
->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));
 $this->em->remove($deleteFile);

$move = $deleteFile->
rename('%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads/files/trashedFiles',$name); //This section is my problem???
```

UploadedFile Entity:

```
/**
* UploadedFile
* @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable
* @ORM\Table(name="uploaded_files")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UploadedFile\UploadedFileRepository")
* @Vich\Uploadable
*/
class UploadedFile
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="file", fileNameProperty="uniqueName")
 * @var File
 */
private $documentFile;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="orginal_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $orginalName;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="integer")
 */
private $size;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="unique_name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $uniqueName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $Url;

/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $active;

use TimestampableEntity;

use SoftDeleteableEntity;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set orginalName
 *
 * @param string $orginalName
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function setOrginalName($orginalName)
{
    $this->orginalName = $orginalName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get orginalName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getOrginalName()
{
    return $this->orginalName;
}

/**
 * Set size
 *
 * @param integer $size
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function setSize($size)
{
    $this->size = $size;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get size
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSize()
{
    return $this->size;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Set uniqueName
 *
 * @param string $uniqueName
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function setUniqueName($uniqueName)
{
    $this->uniqueName = $uniqueName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get uniqueName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUniqueName()
{
    return $this->uniqueName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->Url;
}

/**
 * @param string $Url
 */
public function setUrl($Url)
{
    $this->Url = $Url;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isActive()
{
    return $this->active;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $active
 */
public function setActive($active)
{
    $this->active = $active;
}

/**
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDocumentFile(File $file = null)
{
    $this->documentFile = $file;

    if ($file) {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getDocumentFile()
{
    return $this->documentFile;
}
```

}

Comment: what error do you get?  are you missing `/web/` in your uploads path ?

Comment: And Show your UploadedFile entity otherwise its difficult to answer this

Comment: @johnSmith I added entity.

Answer (score 1):

After removing an instance from the entity manager, you wont have any access to it

```
$this->em->remove($deleteFile); // $deleteFile = null
```

The concept of soft delete, is actually a way of not deleting the entity, but add another boolean field to it which represents if the file is 'deleted' or not.

If you still want to keep you logic, first move the file to another folder, and than remove the entity from db.

Hope this helps!